# How do I make a function triggered by pressing right click?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard-events, right-click

I'm working on a game involving turtle for a school project and I want to end it when the player right clicks on anything but I've been researching for ages and I can't find how to key bind a right click and every module i import but turtle won't work.

I tried importing pyautogui, pydirectimput, tkinter and many more to try and find work arounds becuase it has to be a right click but the imports wont work. I've tried treating it like a normal key bind but that won't work; maybe I'm not using capitals and underscores correctly, I don't know how to do it and it's due in 7 hours. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know turtle much, but I think this should work:

```
def bar():
    # do stuff here

# Test this with either a 2 or a 3, idk which one it is
turtle.onscreenclick(bar, 2, True)
```

It will bind the right click event to this bar function.
Tell me if it does not work!

Edit: I had used the wrong method sorry!
It's actually "onscreenclick".